# No protocol binding matches the given address for WCF-service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, svc

I am running a website (ASP.Net 4) using IIS6. I get the following error message when I try to run a svc-service:

> No protocol binding matches the given address
>   'http://www.holtalen.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc'`.
>
> Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>   Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No protocol binding matches the given address
>   'http://www.holtalen.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc'.
>   Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS
>   configuration.
>   Source Error:
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location
>   of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace
>   below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: No protocol binding matches the given address
>   'http://www.holtalen.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc'.
>   Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS
>   configuration.]
>   [ServiceActivationException: No protocol binding matches the given address
>   'http://www.holtalen.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc'.
>   Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS
>   configuration.]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +679246
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +190
>              System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication
>   context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean
>   ensureWFService) +234
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +355
>              System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously

I have added the extension .svc as an application mapping for the site.

Parts of Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="udpTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.UdpTransportElement, EPiServer.Events" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <services>
      <!-- Before deployment, you should remove the returnFaults behavior configuration to avoid disclosing information in exception messages -->
      <service name="EPiServer.Events.Remote.EventReplication" behaviorConfiguration="DebugServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint name="RemoteEventServiceEndPoint" contract="EPiServer.Events.ServiceModel.IEventReplication" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RemoteEventsBinding" address="soap.udp://239.255.255.19:5000/RemoteEventService" />
        <!-- Uncomment this endpoint and the "RemoteEventServiceClientEndPoint" to enable remote events
            <endpoint name="RemoteEventServiceEndPoint"
                    contract="EPiServer.Events.ServiceModel.IEventReplication"
                    binding="customBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="RemoteEventsBinding"
                    address="soap.udp://239.255.255.19:5000/RemoteEventService" />-->
      </service>

        <service name="SSP.eDemokrati.Templates.Services.eDemokratiService"  >
                <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
                <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
                <endpoint contract="SSP.eDemokrati.Templates.Services.eDemokratiService" binding="webHttpBinding"  />
                <host>
     <baseAddresses>
     <add baseAddress="http://www.holtalen.kommune.no/" />
      <!--<add baseAddress="http://172.28.160.23:80/" />
     --> 

     </baseAddresses>
    </host>
       </service>



      <!-- In order to get fault information from the server for debug purposes, add behaviorConfiguration="DebugServiceBehaviour" to the endpoint "RemoteEventServiceEndPoint" -->
    </services>


    <client>
      <endpoint name="RemoteEventServiceClientEndPoint" address="soap.udp://239.255.255.19:5000/RemoteEventService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RemoteEventsBinding" contract="EPiServer.Events.ServiceModel.IEventReplication" />
      <!-- Uncomment this endpoint and the "RemoteEventServiceEndPoint" to enable remote events
        <endpoint name="RemoteEventServiceClientEndPoint"
           address="soap.udp://239.255.255.19:5000/RemoteEventService"
           binding="customBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="RemoteEventsBinding"
           contract="EPiServer.Events.ServiceModel.IEventReplication" />-->

    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DebugServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="RemoteEventsBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <udpTransport multicast="True" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
   </bindings>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
   <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="Templates/eDemokrati/services/eDemokratiService.svc" service="SSP.eDemokrati.Templates.Services.eDemokratiService" />
   </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

What configuration should I add to IIS in order to get this to work?

Comment: The extension (`.svc`) is _not_ the protocol identifier, that's the prefix (`http`, `ftp`, etc.). What bindings do you have in your web.config?

Comment: Have you defined your service endpoint? Share your endpoint definition. I guess you are missing the binding there

Comment: @Grant Thomas, Thanks!
I updated my post with some of the content of web.config

Comment: @nunepascal,
Yes, I have defined it.
But it isn't working despite this.

Comment: @GrantThomas,
webHttpBinding
I thought the problem was fixed, but it still remains.